# How can I temporarily disable Netrw so I can have Telescope at startup?

Tags: neovim, netrw, telescope.nvim

In my current setup, if I enter neovim with `nvim dir`, instead of opening with Netrw, I get the `:Telescope find_files` prompt. To achieve that, I have to disable Netrw, or it opens in the background. Here's the configuration to achieve this:

```lua
-- Disable netrw
vim.g.loaded_netrwPlugin = 1
vim.g.loaded_netrw = 1

-- Open Telescope on startup if the first argument is a directory
local ts_group = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup("TelescopeOnEnter", { clear = true })
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({ "VimEnter" }, {
    callback = function()
        local first_arg = vim.v.argv[3]
        if first_arg and vim.fn.isdirectory(first_arg) == 1 then
            -- Vim creates a buffer for folder. Close it.
            vim.cmd(":bd 1")
            require("telescope.builtin").find_files({ search_dirs = { first_arg } })
        end
    end,
    group = ts_group,
})
```

However, I still want to be able to invoke `:Explore` sometimes, which is not possible with the configuration above.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at https://github.com/nvim-telescope/telescope-file-browser.nvim, it should be customisable enough to add the normal fuzzy finder at startup. It has a hijack_netrw property that you can set to true. When you set it to true it will come up instead of netrw.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you keep this in `init.lua` it should work fine:

```
vim.g.loaded_netrwPlugin = 0
```